# ndarray with 3 dimension into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I know this topic has been asked before, but as i'm new to python I couldn't fully understand how to do that and I would like to get explanations about.
I have ndarray cube (stack of images from the same location with the same size and shape which differs in the wavelength they were taken).
I want to convert this image into pandas dataframe in order to be able to iterate through specific rows.

i'm really confused because of the big number of columns I have: I ahve 1024 columns in each image and that confuse me when I need to index those images.

My end goal is to get in the end the images in structure of df, so maybe it means to have kind of imagecollection that I can iterate rows in each one of them.

this is the code I have written until now:

```
import spectral.io.envi as envi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from spectral import *
import numpy as np

#Create the image path
#the path 
img_path = r'N:\this\is\a\path\capture'
cali_path=r'N:\location\Image_Python'

#the specific file 
img_file = 'emptyname_2019-08-13_11-05-46.hdr'
img_dark= 'DARKREF_emptyname_2019-08-13_11-05-46.hdr'
cali_hdr= 'Radiometric_1x1.hdr'
cali_img = 'Radiometric_1x1.cal'

img= envi.open(os.path.join(img_path,img_file)).load()
img_dark= envi.open(os.path.join(img_path,img_dark)).load()
img_cali= envi.open(os.path.join(cali_path,cali_hdr), image = os.path.join(cali_path,cali_img)).load()

cali_shape=img_cali.shape
dark_shape=img_dark.shape
img_shape=img.shape
print('shape image:',img_shape,'shape dark:',dark_shape,'calibration shape:',cali_shape)

wavelength=[float(i) for i in img.metadata['wavelength']]

#get the exposure time
tint=float(img.metadata['tint'])
print(tint)

#goak: need to reduce the dark reference from DN image.


#step 1: for each column in the dark reference, calculate mean. then reduce this mean line from the DN image.
#we have created average according to the horizontal axix- axis=0, it calculates the mean for the whole column and we get one row.
dark_1024=img_dark.mean(axis=0)

from numpy import asarray
import pandas as pd


img_np=asarray(img)
dark_np=asarray(img_dark)
cali_np=asarray(img_cali)
```

Comment: Why not iterating over the appropriate array-axis?

Comment: As you know, `pandas` dataframes are two dimentionals. To make it 3-dimentionals you would probably need to create a dictionary of df's or something else as ackward, but I'm sure staying with `numpy` would be much better and easier.